# Merge records from two different tables

Tags: select, teradata, tableau-api, join

I have two tables one with 9 fields the other with 12 fields in teradata sql. While i can join on the 9 common fields 3 fields are not joining therefore creating duplicate reads.

```
[Join on t1.field1=t2.field1
And  t1.field2=t2.field2
And  t1.field3=t2.field3
And  t1.field4=t2.field4
And  t1.field5=t2.field5
And  t1.field6=t2.field6
And  t1.field7=t2.field7
And t1.field8=t2.field8
And t1.field9=t2.field9]
```

However I have 3 more fields `t2.field10`, `t2.field11`,`t2.field12`
which is creating duplicate records from `table1`.

Can you advise on how to build a select statement that would not create duplicate of records from `table1`?

table 1

```
<tr>    <th>    semester    </th><th>   country </th><th>   state   </th><th>   county  </th><th>   city    </th><th>   school name </th><th>   type    </th><th>   type2   </th><th>   class   </th><th>   number of students  </th>   </tr>
<tr>    <td>    spring2016  </td><td>   USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   1   </td><td>   331 </td>   </tr>
<tr>    <td>    spring2016  </td><td>   USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   2   </td><td>   487 </td>   </tr>
<tr>    <td>    spring2016  </td><td>   USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   3   </td><td>   329 </td>   </tr>
<tr>    <td>    spring2016  </td><td>   USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   4   </td><td>   400 </td>   </tr>
<tr>    <td>    spring2016  </td><td>   USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   5   </td><td>   225 </td>   </tr>
<tr>    <td>    fall2016    </td><td>   USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   1   </td><td>   249 </td>   </tr>
<tr>    <td>    fall2016    </td><td>   USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   2   </td><td>   136 </td>   </tr>
<tr>    <td>    fall2016    </td><td>   USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   3   </td><td>   140 </td>   </tr>
<tr>    <td>    fall2016    </td><td>   USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   4   </td><td>   444 </td>   </tr>
<tr>    <td>    fall2016    </td><td>   USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   5   </td><td>   371 </td>   </tr>
```

table 2:

```
country </th><th>   state   </th><th>   county  </th><th>   city    </th><th>   school name </th><th>   type    </th><th>   type2   </th><th>   level   </th><th>   class   </th><th>   homework    </th><th>   field trip  </th><th>   tests   </th><th>   planned budget  </th><th>   actual budget   </th>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   1   </td><td>   american literature </td><td>   n   </td><td>   n   </td><td>   8   </td><td>   6856    </td><td>   5800.357992 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   1   </td><td>   geography   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   8   </td><td>   3040    </td><td>   963.4004114 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   1   </td><td>   music   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   10  </td><td>   3288    </td><td>   2362.845994 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   2   </td><td>   american literature </td><td>   n   </td><td>   n   </td><td>   8   </td><td>   6984    </td><td>   4368.417857 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   2   </td><td>   british literature  </td><td>   n   </td><td>   n   </td><td>   4   </td><td>   3977    </td><td>   3861.683941 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   2   </td><td>   geography   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   n   </td><td>   5   </td><td>   5358    </td><td>   1727.575547 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   3   </td><td>   biology </td><td>   y   </td><td>   n   </td><td>   6   </td><td>   4490    </td><td>   4241.514602 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   3   </td><td>   british literature  </td><td>   n   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   9   </td><td>   3476    </td><td>   2176.995858 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   3   </td><td>   PE  </td><td>   y   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   7   </td><td>   6060    </td><td>   713.4806136 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   4   </td><td>   biology </td><td>   y   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   8   </td><td>   5059    </td><td>   2269.706168 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   4   </td><td>   music   </td><td>   n   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   8   </td><td>   3250    </td><td>   583.2956503 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   4   </td><td>   PE  </td><td>   n   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   3   </td><td>   3945    </td><td>   577.6461806 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   5   </td><td>   american literature </td><td>   n   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   7   </td><td>   4083    </td><td>   2853.53736  </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   5   </td><td>   music   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   8   </td><td>   3502    </td><td>   1257.361273 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   5   </td><td>   PE  </td><td>   n   </td><td>   n   </td><td>   3   </td><td>   5234    </td><td>   4075.859156 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   1   </td><td>   american literature </td><td>   n   </td><td>   n   </td><td>   8   </td><td>   6856    </td><td>   5800.357992 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   1   </td><td>   geography   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   8   </td><td>   3040    </td><td>   963.4004114 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   1   </td><td>   music   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   10  </td><td>   3288    </td><td>   2362.845994 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   2   </td><td>   american literature </td><td>   n   </td><td>   n   </td><td>   8   </td><td>   6984    </td><td>   4368.417857 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   2   </td><td>   british literature  </td><td>   n   </td><td>   n   </td><td>   4   </td><td>   3977    </td><td>   3861.683941 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   2   </td><td>   geography   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   n   </td><td>   5   </td><td>   5358    </td><td>   1727.575547 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   3   </td><td>   biology </td><td>   y   </td><td>   n   </td><td>   6   </td><td>   4490    </td><td>   4241.514602 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   3   </td><td>   british literature  </td><td>   n   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   9   </td><td>   3476    </td><td>   2176.995858 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   3   </td><td>   PE  </td><td>   y   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   7   </td><td>   6060    </td><td>   713.4806136 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   4   </td><td>   biology </td><td>   y   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   8   </td><td>   5059    </td><td>   2269.706168 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   4   </td><td>   music   </td><td>   n   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   8   </td><td>   3250    </td><td>   583.2956503 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   4   </td><td>   PE  </td><td>   n   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   3   </td><td>   3945    </td><td>   577.6461806 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   5   </td><td>   american literature </td><td>   n   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   7   </td><td>   4083    </td><td>   2853.53736  </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   5   </td><td>   music   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   y   </td><td>   8   </td><td>   3502    </td><td>   1257.361273 </td>   </tr>
USA </td><td>   Illinois    </td><td>   Cook    </td><td>   Chicago </td><td>   x1  </td><td>   elementary  </td><td>   public  </td><td>   5   </td><td>   PE  </td><td>   n   </td><td>   n   </td><td>   3   </td><td>   5234    </td><td>   4075.859156 </td>   </tr>
```

Table 3 output should look like this:

```
</th><th>   type    </th><th>   type2   </th><th>   level </th><th> number of students  </th><th>   class   </th><th>   homework    </th><th>   number of teachers  </th><th>   tests   </th><th>   planned budget  </th><th>   actual budget   </th><th>   tests/student   </th><th>   $planed per student </th><th>   actual $/student    </th>   </tr>
```

however every query i ran i get either duplicate number of students which than either over counts #students/teacher or planned$/student, actual$/student.

I need that if i were to filter based on these three dimensions:
-class
-tests 
-homework

the 
-#teachers/student
-actual$/student
-planned$/student

should be to the lowest order of students per class

i tried to transpose the 3 fields that are on the table 2 only however the problem is that when i plug it in into tableau i am not able to filter them right.

Comment: Kindly share sample data from both tables,Query you tried, result you are getting and your expected result in formatted text (not images)

Comment: i added sample data set

Comment: Your sample data is unreadable. Kindly read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220127/how-to-make-tables-in-good-format-in-asking-questions-here-which-is-understanda) post on how to add table to questions in good format .  Also kindly add sample desired output along with output columns